# Django permission hide "auth|permission"

Tags: python, django, permissions, admin

I've got a Django app 1.7 and we set up some permissions in auth app (which exists by default), because those permissions are not bound to any of our apps, and they appear in the admin permission list like this:

```
auth|permission|<mypermissionname>
```

On another level we've got permissions that are bound to our apps & models so they appear like this:

```
<myapp>|<mymodule>|<mypermissionname>
```

Is there a way to align both? The best case would be to remove the "auth|permission" part from those permissions? They do not have to be renamed in the database, it's just for cosmetics.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        field = super(MyUserAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

        if db_field.name == 'user_permissions':
            perms = []
            for p in Permission.objectds.all():
                if not str(p).startswith('auth'):
                    perms.append(p.name)
            field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(name__in=perms)

        return field
```

And then:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```